# Postman returning HTML login page with keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, postman, microservices, keycloak, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a simple microservices project with an api-gateway, a product service and keycloak as authentication server. I beleive that i made the configuration correctly because on the browser i get the right response, but on postman what i get back as response is the keycloak default login page (on HTML).

This is the response on the browser [image]

This is the postman response [image]

Postman cookies :
[image]
Api-gateway config :

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - TokenRelay
      routes:
        - id: product-resource-server
          uri: http://localhost:9191
          predicates:
            - Path=/product/**
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          my-keycloak-provider:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:2727/auth/realms/demo-microservice-realm
        registration:
          keycloak-spring-gateway-client:
            provider: my-keycloak-provider
            client-id: demo-cloud-gateway-client
            client-secret: 39ea2ef6-90a7-47ca-9892-fda60127f47e
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/keycloak"
```

My service config :

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: http://localhost:2727/auth/realms/demo-microservice-realm/protocol/openid-connect/certs

server:
  port: 9191
```

ProductController :

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping("/product")
//    @RolesAllowed({"product_read"})
    public String getProduct(Principal principal) {
        return "Response from Product Service, User Id:" + principal.getName();
    }
}
```

So what i really wanna know is if this is a postman Bug or it is a config problem (project, keycloak ...).

Actually i can't test any Post resquest for the same raison and because it not possible to test them on the browser.

I hope this is understandable.

Comment: Check and use  `Authorize using browser`

Comment: `authorization_code` grant is browser based flow. 
You may take a look at stored cookies. Normally the `authorization_code` grant redirects you to your IdP (the login page, which you see).

Comment: @jAC: postman cookies ?

Comment: Can you share how do you solve this problem, please? I have the similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I added `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` in the api gateway project and it works fine.
Please refer to this tutorial : [Microservices – Authentication, and Authorization With Keycloak](https://javatodev.com/microservices-authentication-and-authorization-with-keycloak/)

Comment: This lacks a bit of "why" it works. Also, it might not be an optimal solution: you maintain sessions and CSRF protection for requests secured with access tokens. Also, response status is the same (redirect to login) for all unauthorized requests when those issued by OAuth2 REST clients (authorizing requests with tokens, not sessions like "with your browser" in your question) should receive a 401. See my developed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Requests to OAuth2 clients are secured with sessions, not access tokens.

Requests to resource servers are secured with access tokens, not sessions.

In your initial config, the gateway is configured as a client and the API as a resource server. The `TokenRelay` filter on the gateway, replaces the session cookie with an access token before forwarding an incoming request to the API.

Your Postman request does not belong to a session with an authorised client on the gateway (you used Postman itself to fetch a token, not the oauth2Login on the gateway). This is the reason for your Postman request to the gateway being unauthorized with a redirect to login.

If you call the API directly, you won't have the problem.

If the gateway is intended to be used only by OAuth2 REST clients (like Postman, other services with tools like `WebClient` or front-ends with client libs like [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client)), then configure the gateway as a resource server instead (or just remove security from it)

If the gateway is intended to be called by OAuth2 clients (requests authorized with access tokens) and non OAuth2 ones (requests secured with sessions), then I suggest that you define two different entry points on the gateway:

- one with TokenRelay filter and a security filter-chain with "client" configuration (sessions and CSRF protection enabled, oauth2Login, logout, unauthorized requests redirected to login)
- one without the TokenRelay filter and a "resource server" security filter-chain (STATELESS session management, disabled CSRF protection, 401 returned to unauthorized requests.

Use different `@Order` for each security filter-chain bean and a `securityMatcher` at least on the first (the one with lowest order).

Complete sample [here](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff).

Off course, you can also mix client and resource server configurations in a single security filter-chain as done in the tutorial linked in the accepted answer, but it is quite likely that you won't understand as well what you are doing and pull your hair when trying to debug an access issue... Also, maintaining sessions and CSRF protection for requests with an access token is a waste of resources. Last, redirecting to login the  unauthorized requests from OAuth2 REST clients is not adapted.

Comment: I have a question about this setup. What if we have more then one Spring Cloud Gateway apps and behind them we have several duplicated resource servers? Should the use one distributed session cache by Spring Cloud Gateway?

Answer (score 0):

In postman when you use Authorization type oAuth2. Postman redirect you to login page to get access token from keycloak and store it in memory via `Get New Access Token` button. Then when you send a new request to the resource endpoint via the `Send` blue button; Postman sets the available token on a header field (Authorization) and sends it to server. therefore when `Authorization` header not set in your request.(for example for the first time that you not get a new token yet) your gateway detects `not authorize` error and redirects you to login page.

but on browser, the authorization mechanism is different totally in the way you call endpoint. It uses stored cookie (JSESSION) not token. you can test it by delete all stored cookie in your browser.

Comment: There something that i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: No. you did it correct. but you compare two totally different thing. I try to explain differences above.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.

When I sent the token request from Postman, I received a response with 200 code but body was in html, which is useless.

In my case I found out I just wrote wrong url. So the solution was correcting the called url.

Your url should look like this:

http://**{wherever-your-keycloak-runs}**/auth/realms/**{name-of-your-realm}**/protocol/openid-connect/token

But I had mistake in {wherever-your-keycloak-runs} part, so apparently I was calling the wrong part of the keyclock.