# Upgrading to Spring Boot 3 Security - interaction with older security version

Tags: spring, spring-boot, migration, spring-security-6

We are trying to migrate our application to Spring Boot 3+ version, with Spring Security 6+.
Our project depends on a library (oauth2), which uses Spring Boot 2+ version with WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and other deprecated staff. We cannot change the library and when we start the application we are getting:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Is that possible to use Spring Security 6+ on our project without changing the library?

Comment: Does project represent resource server part from oAuth2.0 standard or client side ?

Comment: by the way, i wrote an answer to also a relevant question about your topic. Just check [Approved answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76315238/migrate-spring-security-configuration-to-spring-cloud-2022-0-4/76938976#76938976). Can you check and tell me it it helped you ?

Comment: @AndreiLisa, client side

Comment: also a good answer in my opinion was provided by @ch4mp, in above linked Q/A. From there will be a good start for migration

Answer (score 0):

My answer would have been more helpful if you had specified what this lib is and if you had provided your security conf, but to this question, all we can answer is: *no, you can't use a lib written for Spring Security 5 in a project with Spring Security 6*.

This is a very frequent question from users of the Keycloak adapters for Spring and the answer is to remove this dependency and to write the security conf yourself (or to use another lib with similar features and compatible with security 6).

As exposed in [my answer to using Keycloak with Boot 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74571191/use-keycloak-spring-adapter-with-spring-boot-3/74572732#74572732), writing such conf can be rather simple.