# Accessing endpoints with Postman, Keycloak authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I have a Spring Boot 2.6 application and I am using Keycloak for authentication, with role based access. When accessing the endpoints from the browser, it works perfect (redirects to authentication page, gives access based on roles). But I tried to do this from Postman and it is not working. I get an access token, put it in the header and still I get the Authentication page as a response (see picture below)

[image]

Maybe I did something wrong in the Security configuration?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class KeycloakSecurityConfig {

    @Value("${eval.required.role.name}")
    private String requiredRoleName;

    @Bean
    CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        CorsFilter filter = new CorsFilter();
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, KeycloakLogoutHandler keycloakLogoutHandler) throws Exception {

        http.addFilterBefore(corsFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class);

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html", "/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/logout").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().hasAuthority(requiredRoleName);

        http.oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .logout()
                .addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler)
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/");

        return http.build();
    }


    @Component
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    static class GrantedAuthoritiesMapperImpl implements GrantedAuthoritiesMapper {

        @Override
        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> mapAuthorities(Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
            Set<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();

            authorities.forEach(authority -> {
                if (OidcUserAuthority.class.isInstance(authority)) {
                    final var oidcUserAuthority = (OidcUserAuthority) authority;
                    mappedAuthorities.addAll(extractAuthorities(oidcUserAuthority.getIdToken().getClaims()));

                } else if (OAuth2UserAuthority.class.isInstance(authority)) {
                    try {
                        final var oauth2UserAuthority = (OAuth2UserAuthority) authority;
                        final var userAttributes = oauth2UserAuthority.getAttributes();
                        mappedAuthorities.addAll(extractAuthorities(userAttributes));

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            });

            return mappedAuthorities;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
        private static Collection<GrantedAuthority> extractAuthorities(Map<String, Object> claims) {
            if (claims != null) {
                ArrayList<String> roles = (ArrayList<String>) claims.get("Roles");
                List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>(roles.size());
                for (String role : roles) {
                    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
                }

                return authorities;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

What should I add to the code? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postman returning HTML login page with keycloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69721548/postman-returning-html-login-page-with-keycloak)

Comment: I already answered this question from you in a comment and detailed the why in an added answer to the thread proposed for duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76325276/619830